# is there a way to easily log all context information from within an azure apim policy?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Is there a way to easily log all context information from within an Azure APIM policy?  The context variable has many available properties:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn910913.aspx#ContextVariables

However, based on some fiddling around it seems like each of these properties needs to be specified explicitly for logging. Do you know if there's a way to simply log all available context information like context.ToString()?  Simply including context or context.ToString() within the policy does not appear to allow the policy to compile.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to serialize the object into string. checkout http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

```
Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "Apple";
product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small" };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
// {
//   "Name": "Apple",
//   "Expiry": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//   "Sizes": [
//     "Small"
//   ]
// }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working.  You can serialize some parts of the context object, like user, but the request and response objects are failing to serialize properly.

Comment: in this case, you have to create your own object, and have a helper method maybe to read all the information you need from those object and serialize your own object

Comment: Exactly.  A bug has been filed to try and resolve this issue though.